# Cisco AnyConnect denies connection after failing to recognize antivirus

Tags: vpn, anti-virus

First I'd like to say...

1. I don't typically install antivirus on my computers but I had to make an exception for a client.
2. I've talked to their help desk about this issue and aside from providing a spreadsheet of approved antivirus apps for Mac I have had no luck getting AnyConnect to recognize that I have installed one. Tried a few actually.
3. They did ask some other people in company on Macs and they said they were running the AnyConnect in a windows vm and I'm guessing making windows act like a proxy for specific traffic. Not exactly sure how that is being configured, but that's my last resort.

So now the question, does anyone know what AnyConnect is checking? Is it a path? Or something else? I've been wondering if I can force it or fake it. My client doesn't want me to settle for Windows since their network people say they support it. No response from network dept on that so I'm on my own or have to hack together some obtuse solution.

So if anyone has any suggestions that would be awesome.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I cannot say I fully grok how anti-virus comes into play with your VPN software, but AnyConnect is a notoriously flaky VPN client. You are better off using the native VPN connection built into the OS. You will need to create a new Cisco VPN connection and most importantly, You will need the gateway IP, Group ID, and shared secret for your connection from your IT folk. You may find them quite reasonable about giving your that especially if you are are being locked out and can solve your problem with some self-sufficiency.

Comment: Oh! I didn't realize it was possible to connect with the native VPN settings. I had heard somewhere that Cisco was doing something semi proprietary. I will give that a try today and report back. Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know I didn't forget to update. I have a call later today with a NetOps person for working though the issue. So I'll post an update with whatever happens with that.

Comment: More bad news. So I talked to a network person which I think is outsourced or something. They asked me to open IE after I explained to them the problem was on a mac. This is just frustrating.

Comment: Ouch. They wouldn't give you the information you sought so you could configure it yourself? Or they *couldn't*? Sounds like the latter. Sorry- I know what that's like.

Comment: Managed to get network people and Cisco on a Screensharing session. Seeing the mgmt tool for Cisco was helpful and I saw the solution right away. The challenge was getting the outsourced dept to understand what we needed them to change. It took three hrs and Cisco support assuring them they wouldn't drop the VPN by modifying the rule for Mac OS devices. They had added a temp rule to ignore my users av scan failure but the issue turned out to be the part where it is incorrectly checking for a specific  av vs the list of many they sent me. So I installed that specific one and boom! It worked!

Comment: So thank you for your help and turned out it nothing would have fixed it except dumb luck by installing some random (shady looking) antivirus. It was super educational getting to see how Ciscos VPN is managed tho. I think I might see a way to fake it in the future. But too far behind from this to play with that now.

Comment: That's a tough fix to have to install unwelcome software, but at least you are working.